# How do i Reverse Capitalize And Separate Words By Line Using String In Java?

Tags: java

The input is: `i love cake`

The output needs to be: `Cake Love I`

But the actual result is: `I Love Cake`

What I've got:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern; 
public class yellow {

    static String reverseWords(String str){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
        String[] temp = pattern.split(str);
        String result = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            if (i == temp.length - 1)
                result = temp[i] + result;
            else
                result = " " + temp[i] + result;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String source = "i love cake";
        StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();

        String[] strArr = source.split(" ");
        for (String str : strArr) {
            char[] stringArray = str.trim().toCharArray();
            stringArray[0] = Character.toUpperCase(stringArray[0]);
            str = new String(stringArray);

            res.append(str).append(" ");
        }
        System.out.print(res.toString());
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That seems correct as you're not reversing the order anywhere, consider changing your `for` loop (or use your own method). Also look into the newline character `\n`.

Comment: So, you got the uppercasing right. Now you need to reverse the array. Note that your reverseWords method is never called anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String str : strArr) {

}
```

This loops forward. What you want is to loop backwards, or to place elements into the string backwards. I recommend you loop backwards and print as you go:

```
for (int i = strArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    char[] stringArray = strArr[i].trim().toCharArray();
    stringArray[0] = Character.toUpperCase(stringArray[0]);
    System.out.println(new String(stringArray));
}
```

Or, you could use that convenient `reverseWords` method that you never use anywhere... though looping backwards is faster. Probably.

Comment: when i replace it the capital letters are gone how would i bring them back?

Comment: @MadChuner You have to paste the code that's capitalizing the words into my for loop.

Comment: im sorry how do i do that?

Comment: error cant find symbol: System.out.println(line); sorry im not good at this xD

Comment: @MadChuner Oh sorry, I deleted a variable without checking for more occurrences lol. See edit :P

Comment: @MadChuner Dude did you just assume my gender /s

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]
Call this for each line with string s, then print a line break (If you have multiple sentences & expect them in their own lines).

```
void reverseCamel(String s){
    String[] ar = s.split("\\s+");
    for(int i = ar.length - 1;i>=0;i--){
        ar[i][0] = Character.toUpperCase(ar[i][0]);
        System.out.print(ar[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, this does not directly answer OP's question because it does not print on separate lines. Secondly, have you seen my answer? What improvements does your answer place over mine? Thirdly, please test your code first; `length` is a field of `T[]`, not a method. Besides that, while this code technically works, please add an explanation so that OP knows how to use this code; just posting code can be confusing and not helpful.

Comment: where do i add that in?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    reverse("I Love Cake");
}

public static void reverse( String string){
    String[] word =string.split(" "); // split by spaces
    int i = word.length-1;
    while (i>=0){
       // System.out.print(word[i].toUpperCase()+" ");//if you want in upper case
        System.out.print(word[i]+" ");
        i--;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to reverse the String.

```
String[] words = source.split("\\s");
String reversedString = "";
for(int i = words.length -1; i>=0; i--){
    reversedString += words[i] + " ";
}
```

Then, you know that the ASCII code of `'a'` character is 97, `'A'` is 65. To convert from lower case to capital you substract 32. All capitals are between 65 and 92. All small letters are between 97 and 124.
You want to capitalize only letters at the beginning of a word (preceded by a space or first letter).

```
String capitalCase = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < reversedString.length(); i++) {
            char c = reversedString.charAt(i);
            if (c >= 97 && c <= 124) {
                if (i == 0) c -= 32;
                else if ((reversedString.charAt(i - 1) + "").equals(" ")) c -= 32;
            }
            capitalCase += c;
        }
```

And here you go now `System.out.println(capitalCase);`

**Overall, you will have the following code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class yellow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string:");
        String source = s.nextLine();

        String[] words = source.split("\\s");
        String reversedString = "";
        for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reversedString += words[i] + " ";
        }

        String capitalCase = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < reversedString.length(); i++) {
            char c = reversedString.charAt(i);
            if (c >= 97 && c <= 124) {
                if (i == 0) c -= 32;
                else if ((reversedString.charAt(i - 1) + "").equals(" ")) c -= 32;
            }
            capitalCase += c;
        }

        System.out.println(capitalCase);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a string:
i love cake
Cake Love I
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java 8 * Apache Commons Lang**

```
public static String reverseWordsInString(String str) {
    List<String> words = Pattern.compile("\\s+").splitAsStream(str)
                                .map(StringUtils::capitalize)
                                .collect(LinkedList::new, LinkedList::addFirst, (a, b) -> a.addAll(0, b));
    return words.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(StringUtils.SPACE));
}
```

**Java 8**

```
public static String reverseWordsInString(String str) {
    List<String> words = Pattern.compile("\\s+").splitAsStream(str)
                                .map(word -> Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1).toLowerCase())
                                .collect(LinkedList::new, LinkedList::addFirst, (a, b) -> a.addAll(0, b));
    return words.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```